# Implementing a Search History feature in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, serialization

I've got a search page at the moment which will load a list of results for a web-service, but when I return to the search page I would like to '**save**' **whatever was entered** (e.g. 'resto italian') and then display that entry and previous entries into a table view below, like in my following image:

[image]

My plan was to use property list serialization - if there isn't already a list, create a property list called history.plist, and populate it with each search term that is made, and display the nearest ten in the table view like above.

**What I've tried:**

```
// should create history.plist
- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"history.plist"];
}

/* This is the action for when 'search' is clicked - calls the method above to create 
a new plist if it's not already created. 
I then try to display the contents of the of the file in the textfield itself 
(for testing purposes) but it's not saving/displaying properly at the moment. */

- (IBAction)saveHistory:(id)sender {        
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
       NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
       for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)); i++) {
            UITextField *theField = self.searchHistory;
            theField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", array];
       }
    }        
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:app];        
}
```

Any links to tutorials attempting to do this, suggestions towards what I should do, or improvements to what I have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't do this with a plist (unless there's a requirement). I have to believe CoreData is faster with more sorting capabilities.

Comment: Step 1. save each search in coreData as a string with a timestamp.
Step 2. create a tableView that populates those strings in reverse chronological order using a Core Data Fetch request.
Step 3. add a method on didSelectCell for the tableView to research on that recorded history string.

I think each coreData insert object should only need string and timestamp for attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix the problem:

```
// This is inside viewDidLoad    
UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self     
          selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)                                                                
          name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
          object:myApp];

// This is inside my table view - where I'm loading the file data to display in table cells
NSString *myPath = [self dataFilePath];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];
if (fileExists) {
   NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
      for (int i = 0; i < values.count; i++) {
         cell.historyDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [values objectAtIndex:i]];
      }
}

// This is the file path for history.plist
- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"history.plist"];
}

// This is my search button - I want to save whatever was typed in the text field, into history.plist, to display in my tableview whenever a user goes to it.     
- (IBAction)saveHistory:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
    if(searchInputTextField.text.length > 0)
         [values addObject:searchInputTextField.text];
    [values writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];    
    [leTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use my suggest in comments, but here's some edits to your code that might help in the meantime.

```
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        for (int i = 0; i <array.count; i++) {
            //I don't know what this line means
            UITextField *theField = self.searchHistory;
            //Change this line to this
            theField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
```

Comment: You should put your suggestions in this answer as well so they're collected in the same place.

Comment: I wouldn't do this with a plist (unless there's a requirement). I have to believe CoreData is faster with more sorting capabilities. – Eric 20 mins ago 
 
Step 1. save each search in coreData as a string with a timestamp. Step 2. create a tableView that populates those strings in reverse chronological order using a Core Data Fetch request. Step 3. add a method on didSelectCell for the tableView to research on that recorded history string. I think each coreData insert object should only need string and timestamp for attributes.

Comment: I would say that the speed of Core Data is only meaningfully better on very large data sets. On small ones (anything under a few thousand rows or so), the overhead of writing and reading a plist file is negligible.

Comment: using plist approach probably ok, but you should still look through my code edits, I think rather than creating textfields by array index, using a tableView and populating them is 100X better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your saveHistory function by below way:

```
- (IBAction)saveHistory:(id)sender
{
      NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]];
      if(searchInputTextField.text.length > 0)
           [values addObject:searchInputTextField.text];
      [values writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

      [leTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return values.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil)
     {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     }
     cell.textLabel.text = [values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Core Data, creating a class, i.e. `HistoryRecord` with attributes `termSearched` and `timestamp` of type NSString and NSDate respectively.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface HistoryRecordManagedObject : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *termSearched;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *timestamp;

+ (NSArray *)findEntity:(NSString *)entity withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "HistoryRecordManagedObject.h"

@implementation HistoryRecordManagedObject

@dynamic termSearched;
@dynamic timstamp;

+ (NSArray *)findEntity:(NSString *)entity withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
{
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects;

        /* After set all properties, executes fetch request */
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entity
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDesc];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        [fetchRequest release];


    return fetchedObjects;
}

@end
```

Of course that's not just this! There are some extra stuff that must be done to use Core Data such as create the model. Read a little about it! It's worth!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the action for searching, just save the search result to NSUserDefaults.

```
    NSMutableArray *searches = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"searches"];
[searches insertObject:textField.text atIndex:0];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:searches forKey:@"searches"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then load the same array for the tables data source and reload the table in viewwillappear and when keyboard is dismissed.